# Remove an attribute from shelve

Tags: python, shelve, unshelve

I recently started using the shelve module when I needed to save a lot of variables that constantly changed each time the script was ran.
Sadly, I'm very inexperience with python in general, and even less so with how shelve works.  I removed a function from the script, and now my shelved file no longer works.

I want to fix this issue and retain the shelved file, or at least salvage the variables that I need from the file.